# Large table taking forever to return query results

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I'm working on a [Rails+PostgreSQL] project where we have a table called attempts that has 13,578,350 rows.

Getting that count (`Attempt.count`, which converts to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "attempts"`) takes between 17 and 30 seconds (27.6495 seconds on first attempt, 17.765 seconds a few days later on second attempt).

Any query related to that table is taking FOREVER. I assume that this is related to the table size, but I can't be sure, as I've seen larger tables in other projects that return counts much faster.

What can we do about this? How can we get these queries to take less time?

The table has the following columns:

```
  create_table "attempts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "problem_id"
    t.integer  "sprint_id"
    t.datetime "started_at"
    t.datetime "ended_at"
    t.boolean  "correct"
    t.float    "seconds"
    t.integer  "weight"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
    t.string   "attempted_answer"
    t.boolean  "is_outdated",      default: false
    t.string   "track",            default: "whole_numbers"
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.index ["problem_id"], name: "index_attempts_on_problem_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["sprint_id"], name: "index_attempts_on_sprint_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Some further examples of queries that take a long time:

```
irb(main)> Attempt.count
**(22917.9ms)**  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "attempts"
=> 13578350
irb(main)> Attempt.where(is_outdated: true).size
**(23731.2ms)**  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "attempts" WHERE "attempts"."is_outdated" = $1  [["is_outdated", "t"]]
=> 942301
irb(main)> Attempt.where(student_id: [167550, 136661, 142537])
**(22147.5ms)**  SELECT "attempts".* FROM "attempts" WHERE "attempts"."student_id" IN (167550, 136661, 142537)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

The specific query that is literally freezing when I do it is more complicated, but seems to be freezing due to this `attempts` table (it is lightning fast when there are 0 `student` objects, but when it has to access `attempts` through a number of students, it freezes). I'll put that query here just for reference, but I do not think that the complexity of this query is related, it seems like the `attempts` table is the root of the issue and this query is just exacerbating the issue that we've been facing for a while with this `attempts` table.

```
SELECT u.id as student_id,
               u.name as student_name,
               COUNT(a.id) as attempts_count,
               COUNT(a.id) filter (WHERE a.correct = true) as attempts_correct , 
               ROUND(COUNT(a.id) filter (WHERE a.correct = true) * 1.0 / COUNT(a.id),2) as attempts_correct_percent
        FROM users u

        JOIN lateral (
          SELECT DISTINCT attempts.id,student_id,correct, attempts.started_at
          FROM attempts
          LEFT OUTER JOIN problems ON attempts.problem_id IN (#{([-1]+problem_ids).join(",")})
          WHERE student_id=u.id
          ORDER BY attempts.started_at DESC
          LIMIT 20
        ) a ON u.id=a.student_id

        WHERE u.id IN (#{([-1]+student_ids).join(",")})
        GROUP by u.id
        HAVING (COUNT(a.id) filter (WHERE a.correct = true) * 1.0 / COUNT(a.id)) < 0.8
        AND COUNT(a.id) > 19
        ORDER by u.id;"
```

Comment: I wouldn't doubt your main query that's freezing is part of the issue, but even more apparent to me is the fact that your `attempts` table has has indexes on `problem_id` and `sprint_id` but none of your example queries leverage those indexes. In fact, one predicate against the `attempts` table in your main query is on `student_id`. So creating an index on `student_id` would likely be beneficial here. I'm also sure if you ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (which you should add to your post) on your query, it would expose similar information.

Comment: And to prove out it's not just a size of table problem (or to disprove "*Any query related to that table is taking FOREVER*"), rather it's an indexing one, if you ran `SELECT problem_id FROM attempts WHERE problem_id = SomeSpecificProblemId`, I would bet my money you'd get results very quickly.

Comment: Thank you.. You were right, querying with `problem_id` was lightning fast. I then added an index on `student_id` and then queries against `student_id` were also lightning fast. And as a result, the main query is now LIGHTNING FAST. wow.

I wonder though, why does getting a count for this table take 20-30 seconds? I feel like I've gotten counts of larger tables before and it did not take that long.

Comment: It could be explained if your table is quite active with many `UPDATE`s, `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s - the records could become scattered throughout the pages and files, and that plus multiple record versions (are you running any long-running analytical queries? Do you have many locks (pg_lock)? With poor design and programming, even a (not huge by today's standards) 13M record table can start to slow down!

Comment: @vérace That would make sense in our production database, but I'm querying on a COPY of the production database from my local environment (the database is a remote copy stored on Aiven.io). It doesn't get updated at all, it got cloned about a month ago and just gets used by one other developer and myself, with no active users doing anything to it. :head_scratch:

Comment: Have you run the query in production? Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for **all** tables in the query. Please add the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` for the slow query - or rather, both the fast and slow queries.

Comment: Have you run VACUUM on the copy?